# How can I check if a block of multiple lines matches certain criteria, without loops?

Tags: r, large-data

I have a data set with 2 million lines, so loops are not an option.
The problem is about as follows:

- Each line is a transaction by a person.
- A person can have multiple transactions.
- A transaction can have multiple lines.
- Transactions can have different types.

I need to check if the order of transaction types for each person is realistic. You can't close an account before you opened an account, stuff like that.

So basically:

```
PersonID TransID TransType
----------------------------
1        1       open
1        2       withdraw
1        2       withdraw
1        3       close
2        1       withdraw
2        1       withdraw
2        2       close
```

Now Person 2 withdrew and closed an account without opening it. That's an error. So I want the index of the last line of person 2.

There are tons of rules, what can go before what and under what circumstances so what I need is like a way to code:

FROM INDEX a TO b, CHECK IF x OCCURS BEFORE y THEN REPEAT FROM INDEX b+1 TO c UNTIL WE ARE THROUGH THE ENTIRE DATASET

What exactly the result is, is not that important, if I get the IDs of the people, or a vector of the rows where a rule has been violated is not that important.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are tons of solutions related to this, but we can't help you if your question is approached from different points of view!

Comment: If this is just an example of one of those "tons of rules"  then you will need to offer the form in which these rules are encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you break this down into multiple steps,

Break out one data frame for each person,

then one for each transaction.

Then apply your rules appropriately. You will probably have some person level rules and some transaction level rules.

Here is some code to start you off.

```
    data <- data.frame(PersonID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2),  
                      TransID = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1),
                      TransType = c("open", 
                                    "withdraw", 
                                    "withdraw", 
                                    "close", 
                                    "withdraw", 
                                    "withdraw", 
                                    "close"))
    
    result <- split.data.frame(data, data$PersonID) 
    
    result
```

This will return one data frame per person.

Comment: Offering a plan expressed in natural language is a start but SO is all about code that succeeds. You are unlikely to get much favorable response to answers without coding.

Comment: Comments are not good for code in either questions or answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing